# Dataset on bordering countries

Tags: data, borders

Is there a publicly available dataset somewhere that lists all country-adjacencies (pairs of countries that share a land border)?

Background: I want to programmatically access the list of countries that share a (land)border with country X.

Example: I programmatically want to access all of Luxembourgs neighboring countries, so having a dataset that contains these entries:

```
LU BE
LU DE
LU FR
```

Would allow my program to do useful stuff with the list [BE,DE,FR].

Comment: I've never heard of such database, but it should be quite straightforward to compute with most GIS software and a GIS dataset of the countries. What software do you work with ?

Comment: Not using any GIS software, although I do have a postgis install available.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You can work this out using the GeoNames RDF endpoint (and probably with other end points too). So for example to find the neighbours of France you call

```
  http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/neighbours.rdf
```

which returns the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:gn="http://www.geonames.org/ontology#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:wgs84_pos="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/3175395/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3175395/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Italy</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2921044/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2921044/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Germany</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2510769/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2510769/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Spain</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2802361/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2802361/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Belgium</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2658434/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2658434/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Switzerland</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/3041565/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3041565/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Andorra</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2960313/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2960313/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Luxembourg</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/2993457/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2993457/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Monaco</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/3017382/"/>
</gn:Feature>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the geonames APIs. After looking around a bit this is very close to what I needed: http://api.geonames.org/neighboursJSON?country=NL&username=<username>

Answer (score 3):

There is the free open source dataset of the neighbouring countries at https://github.com/geodatasource/country-borders in case anyone is interested. I am also part of the contributor to this list.

Comment: terrific, I will incorporate your efforts here: https://github.com/i-rocky/country-list-js/issues/8